# Can I output large numeric to csv as a string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a txt file that has columns several columns and some with large numbers and when I read it in through python and output it to a csv the numbers change and I lose important info. Example of txt file:

```
Identifier
12450006300638672
12450006300638689
12450006300638693
```

Example csv output:

```
Identifier  Changed_format_in_csv
1.245E+16   12450006300638600
1.245E+16   12450006300638600
1.245E+16   12450006300638600
```

Is there a way I can get the file to output tho a csv without it changing the large numbers. I have a lot of other columns that are a mix between string and numeric data type, but I was just thinking if I could output everything as a string it would be fine.

This is what I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd 

file1 = 'file.txt'

df = pd.read_csv(file1, sep="|", names=['Identifier'], index_col=False, dtype=str)

df.to_csv('file_new.csv', index=False)
```

I want the csv file to output like the txt file looks. Was hoping setting dtype=str would help, but it doesn't. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i don't think this is a python question, rather microsoft excel is truncating your large ints. try this https://superuser.com/questions/437764/why-is-excel-truncating-my-16-digit-numbers

Comment: when you say `output` are you talking about the display when you run `df.head()` or something else?

Comment: @Kenan When I write it to the csv file and then open it, it truncates the large numbers as in the second chunk of code above. That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short story:**

I think this problem is related to the data type pandas is interpreting the content of 'file.txt'.
You could try:

```
df = df.assign(Identifier=lambda x: x['Identifier'].astype(int))
```

**Long story:**

I created file.txt with this content:

```
12450006300638672
12450006300638689
12450006300638693
```

Using pandas v0.23.3, I couldn't reproduce your problem with your displayed code, as shown here:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep="|", names=['Identifier'], index_col=False, dtype=str)
>>> df.to_csv('file_new.csv', index=False)
>>> print(df)
          Identifier
0  12450006300638672
1  12450006300638689
2  12450006300638693
>>> exit()

$ cat file_new.csv 
Identifier
12450006300638672
12450006300638689
12450006300638693
```

But I could reproduce your problem using **pd.read_csv(..., dtype=float)** instead:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep="|", names=['Identifier'], index_col=False, dtype=float)
>>> df.to_csv('file_new.csv', index=False)
>>> print(df)
     Identifier
0  1.245001e+16
1  1.245001e+16
2  1.245001e+16
>>> exit()

$ cat file_new.csv
Identifier
1.2450006300638672e+16
1.2450006300638688e+16
1.2450006300638692e+16
```

It seems to be your case, where integer numbers are interpreted as float numbers.
If for some reason you can't interpret them as integers, you could do as follows:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep="|", names=['Identifier'], index_col=False, dtype=float)
>>> print(df)
     Identifier
0  1.245001e+16
1  1.245001e+16
2  1.245001e+16
>>> df = df.assign(Identifier=lambda x: x['Identifier'].astype(int))
>>> print(df)
          Identifier
0  12450006300638672
1  12450006300638688
2  12450006300638692
>>> df.to_csv('file_new.csv', index=False)
>>> exit()

$ cat file_new.csv
Identifier
12450006300638672
12450006300638688
12450006300638692
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not pandas that's changing the large numbers, it's the app you're using to view the CSV. To hint to CSV apps that those numbers should be treated as strings, make sure that they're quoted in the output:

```py
import csv

df.to_csv('file_new.csv', index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

It should look like this:

```
"Identifier"
"12450006300638672"
"12450006300638689"
"12450006300638693"
```

Comment: Changing the datatype of these values could have some unintended side effects though. Be careful with this

Comment: A CSV doesn't have types, it's just text. Quotes (when unnecessary, like in this case) are just hints to the apps that consume them.